# Catching Keypresses on Windows with Python using MSVCRT when terminal window not in Focus

Tags: python, windows, keypress, msvcrt, getch

I want to be able to use the `msvcrt` package in python to catch keypresses via the `msvcrt.getch()` method but it appears the the terminal window needs to be in focus for it to work. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Since input only ever goes to the foreground window, the process calling `getch` obviously must be the foreground process. You cannot change the rules. However, you didn't ask about the real problem you are trying to solve. What is it?

Comment: Well I have Python sending messages to my arduino controlling an LED strip when I press keys on my keyboard so I want to be able to detect key presses even when the terminal window is not in focus. Is there a way to make the window persistent in the background?

Comment: *"Is there a way to make the window persistent in the background?"* - Uhm... no, but even if there were, it wouldn't bring the window to the foreground (which you need for `getch()` to do anything meaningful). If you want to monitor input without having a foreground process, you'll need something like [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx), or install a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx).

Comment: Do you know of a way to implement this in Python or a different Python package I could use for this?

Comment: I don't know whether there are any pre-built Python modules for Raw Input (not the same as Python's `raw_input`, now called `input`). If none of this is available, you could always use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) to access the Windows API directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a python wrapper for Ctypes as suggested by @IInspectable. It wraps the low_level Keyboard hooks with a nice monitor class.

https://github.com/ethanhs/pyhooked

Comment: Did you read the note on the [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) documentation? Here it is: *"[...] In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, **it should monitor raw input instead**. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can. For more information on raw input, see [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536(vs.85).aspx)."*

Comment: I'm lighting up an LED here.  Not exactly computing the answer to the universe. My implementation seems fast enough now.

Comment: The recommendation doesn't pertain to your application only. Low-level keyboard hooks have performance implications on the entire system. For every keyboard input, you get two additional context switches, plus the time it takes for your hook to handle the event. And since Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, someone may find your question, and they **are** computing the answer to the universe.